# Lightweight equivalent of resmon.exe for monitoring multiple servers

Tags: monitoring, nagios, perfmon

I'm looking to set up at-a-glanoe monitoring of CPU. disk, network and memory usage for half-dozen Windows servers.

Windows Performance Monitor is far too complex for what I need - the array of counters and statistics is overwhelming and the UI quickly becomes unusable once you've added more than 5-6 counters to a particular display.

The Resource Monitor (resmon.exe) tool included with Windows 2008 is EXACTLY what I want - but doesn't appear to have any sort of remote monitoring capability.

Is there anything out there (ideally free but I'm happy to pay money if it will save time) that offers this capability?

Thanks,

Dylan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nagios can also monitor Windows servers very well.

For easier setup, consider a commercial (hosted) solution like Cloudkick.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question but when using Perfmon I always switch from graph view to report view. You see the same information without the clutter and load that the graph view imposes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably knock up a script for this and connect to WMI on each server. Does your client computer have [powershell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309377%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) installed? Otherwise [vbscript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389763%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :(
The stats will be at-a-glance, and not a graph of the previous 10 minutes